# Sharp Memory Increase While Selecting Different Objects in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode

Why does the memory-usage on my computer increase sharply with the number of line segments selected, when the line segment is selected first in edit mode? On average there is a 200Mb increase in memory usage for a single line segment! Regarding the model, I only have a multi-res modifier added, does it have something to do with that? Or is it simply a blender optimization problem or a windows memory problem? Sometimes even 64gb of memory will be used!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, “when the line segment is selected first in edit mode“? There’s no other way to select a line segment a.k.a. edge, is there? One has to be in edit mode. Also, if it were not first, what would come first?

Comment: What happens when you are _not_ using Multi-Res?

Comment: When I turn off multi-level precision, there is no change in memory usage.

Comment: When I'm in edit mode, the memory footprint increases dramatically every time I make a selection. So much so that not half an hour later, the memory is full and blender will tend to crash.